# Adding headers to c# HTTP server

Tags: javascript, c#, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make a HTTP server (listener) in c# using the "Simple HTTP server in c#" - (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137979/Simple-HTTP-Server-in-C), and send requests to it using javascript.

This is what the code looks like:

```
The HandleRequest function in c#:
public override void handleGETRequest(HttpProcessor p)
        {
            p.httpHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

            if (p.http_url.Equals("/test"))
            {
                p.outputStream.Write("Test accomplished");
                Console.Log("Server responded to TEST request successfully");
                return;
            }
            if (p.http_url.StartsWith("/goto"))
            {
                string[] args = p.http_url.Split('/');
                //x - [2]
                //y - [3]
                //z - [4]
                //f - [5]
                myPrinter.SendCommand(string.Format("G1X{0}Y{1}F10000", args[2], args[3]));
                p.outputStream.Write("response succeeded");
                Console.Log("goto command was executed");
            }
            if (p.http_url.StartsWith("/commandlist"))
            {
                string[] args = p.http_url.Split('/');
                //[2] - commands
                string[] commands = args[2].Split('$');
                for (int i = 0; i < commands.Length; i++)
                {
                    myPrinter.commands.Add(commands[i]);
                }
                //myPrinter.HandleCommandList();
                p.outputStream.Write("response succeeded");
                Console.Log("goto command was executed");
            }
            if (p.http_url.StartsWith("/execute"))
            {
                p.outputStream.Write("Executing " + myPrinter.commands.Count + " commands\n");
                myPrinter.HandleCommandList();
            }
        }
```

The request sending in JS look like that:

```
function sendGCODE() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://localhost:1300/commandlist/" + document.getElementById("Text1").value;

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var myArr = xmlhttp.responseText;
            myFunction(myArr);
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    function myFunction(arr) {
        alert('Response received');
        document.getElementById("resultP").innerHTML = arr;
    }
}
```

But when I try sending the request from the JS code, it just tells me that "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is missing, and so it can't send the request. I added that header in the beginning of the handleGETRequest() function like that:

```
public override void handleGETRequest(HttpProcessor p)
        {
            p.httpHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

So why doesn't it work? The serverside software doesn't throw an error, but the JS code is still upset because of the missing header.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks! (the rest of the server side code is in the link above)

Comment: Can you use Fiddler (or browser Dev-tools) to check whether the response contains the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should enable CORS for your server to accept those requests, take a look at this [guide](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) , maybe it will help.

Comment: This guide uses something called HttpConfiguration, which is something that isn't used by the code I use... How can this thing be done in the code I  got?

Comment: As i see you are using Mozilla XMLHttpRequest,  think that the problem is in the javascript side, here is another link you can look up info, this is a very thedious subject and it depends on many factors such as server configuration and js request handling, i rembember being hours to make it work on java , i don't know what you are doing wrong but maybe you can find your answer in these pages. 
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Thanks for the help. Eventually I got the problem. I was adding a header but it wasn't sent, so I just had to send the header as a normal line using p.outputStream.WriteLine("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");